# How to create a new XML::DOM::Document root in perl

Tags: xml, perl, dom

I'm trying to modify some code that was using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) to use [`XML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::DOM) instead as the former isn't available on my fatcow server.

How can I set the root document of a `XML::DOM::Document` object?  There is no `setDocumentElement` method in `XML::DOM::Document`.

Here is the code in question (from [`XML::XML2JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::XML2JSON)) with the line I'm trying to figure out how to replace marked with asterisks.

```
=head2 obj2dom

Takes a perl data structure as input. (Must be a hashref.)
Returns an XML::DOM::Document object.    #JMO

This method expects the object to be in the same format as
would be returned by the xml2obj method.

=cut

sub obj2dom
{
    my ( $Self, $Obj ) = @_;

    croak "Object must be a hashref" unless ref($Obj) eq 'HASH';

    my $Version  = $Obj->{ $Self->{attribute_prefix} . 'version' }  || $Obj->{'version'}  || '1.0';
    my $Encoding = $Obj->{ $Self->{attribute_prefix} . 'encoding' } || $Obj->{'encoding'} || 'UTF-8';

    #my $Dom = $XMLPARSER->createDocument( $Version, $Encoding ); #JMO
    my $Dom = XML::DOM::Document->new();                          #JMO
    $Dom->setXMLDecl($Dom->createXMLDecl($Version, $Encoding));   #JMO

    my $GotRoot = 0;

     #delete @$Obj{ grep { /^$Self->{attribute_prefix}/ } keys %$Obj };

    foreach my $Key ( keys %$Obj )
    {
        $Obj->{$Key} = "" unless defined($Obj->{$Key});

        my $RefType = ref( $Obj->{$Key} );
        warn "Value ref type for $Key is: $RefType (value seems to be $Obj->{$Key})" if $Self->{debug};

        my $Name = $Key;

        # replace a "$" in the name with a ":"
        $Name =~ s/([^^])\$/$1\:/;

        if ( $RefType eq 'HASH' )
        {
            warn "Creating root element: $Name" if $Self->{debug};

            croak "You may only have one root element: $Key" if $GotRoot;
            $GotRoot = 1;

            my $Root = $Dom->createElement($Name);
            $Dom->setDocumentElement($Root);        # **********

            $Self->_process_element_hash( $Dom, $Root, $Obj->{$Key} );
        }
        elsif ( $RefType eq 'ARRAY' )
        {
            croak "You cant have an array of root nodes: $Key";
        }
        elsif ( !$RefType )
        {       
            if ( $Obj->{$Key} ne '' )
            {
                unless ($GotRoot)
                {
                    my $Root;
                    eval { $Root = $Dom->createElement($Name) };
                    if ( $@ ) {
                        die "Problem creating root element $Name: $@";
                    }
                    $Dom->setDocumentElement($Root);        # **********
                    $Root->appendText( $Obj->{$Key} );
                    $GotRoot = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
              croak "Invalid data for key: $Key";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            warn "unknown reference: $RefType";
        }
    }

    return $Dom;
}
```

Comment: (You could always install XML:LibXML into your home dir. libxml2 too, if necessary.)

Comment: They won't let you install C code :(

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. Mostly cause that's not really possible. (And there's also the issue that `libxml2` isn't written in C.) You don't need special permissions to install to your home directory.

Comment: I downloaded XML::LibXML and looked at the package and it contains C files.  It's also a wrapper for libxml2, which is "the XML C parser and toolkit developed for the Gnome project".  There is no way I can install either of these on fatcow.

Comment: @ikegami: I wonder on what grounds you claim that libxml2 isn't written in C? And sure, you don't need special permissions to install stuff in your own directory, but you do need *access* to it and a way to run `make` and `gcc`, which is often something that web hosting sites don't let you have, forcing you to do everything through a “console”. I imagine that is the situation that the OP is facing, leaving him no option that I can think of other than creating a duplicate system elsewhere and building everything on that before just copying it over. If you know different then please tell.

Comment: @Borodin, Oops, thought it was C++, but you're completely wrong about the rest. You can install make and gcc in your home dir. And you don't need a console if you can run CGI scripts as the OP can. And as for binaries of libxml2, he doesn't need to build them himself as they are available from the official site. So even in the worst possible case, it's still easier to install XML::LibXML than to rewrite all of his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XML::DOM::Document` object represents the *document root* or *document entity*. Note that there is a distinction between this and the *root element*, which is the only child of the document root and is the outermost element of the XML document.

Once you have a `XML::DOM::Document` object, the first child you add to it using `appendChild` becomes the root element. If you try to append anything other than an *element* node then you will get the error

```
XML::DOM::DOMException(Code=3, Name=HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR, Message=bad node type)
```

or if you attempt to add more than one node you will see

```
XML::DOM::DOMException(Code=3, Name=HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR, Message=document can have only one Element)
```

In other words, the nearest equivalent of your `setDocumentElement` is simply `appendChild`, like this

```
my $Root = $Dom->createElement($Name);
$Dom->appendChild($Root);
```

Here is an example program that builds a complete XML document tree. It appends an element with the tag `root` to the document object, then creates two child elements with tags `child1` and `child2`, appends some text to each of those, and then appends them to the root element.

```
use strict;
use 5.010;
use warnings;

use XML::DOM;

my $dom = XML::DOM::Document->new;
$dom->setXMLDecl($dom->createXMLDecl(qw/ 1.0 UTF-8 /));

my $root = $dom->createElement('root');
$dom->appendChild($root);

for my $tag (qw/ child1 child2 /) {

  my $child = $dom->createElement($tag);
  $root->appendChild($child);

  my $text = $dom->createTextNode("Text for $tag");
  $child->appendChild($text);
}

print $dom->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><child1>Text for child1</child1><child2>Text for child2</child2></root>
```

One last point. Capital letters in identifiers are commonly reserved for globals, such as `Package::Names`. Lexically-scoped variables should have identifiers using lower-case alphanumerics and underscore. However, in this case I realise that the `XML::XML2JSON` module itself breaks this rule!

Comment: Great answer! I still use camelCase for lexically scoped variables, maybe it is just a habit that is difficult to change, but I think there are others that prefer that style too, see for example this discussion: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=990350

Comment: Would you mind voting up my question?  I'm a newbie on StackOverflow and trying to build a reputation - thanks!

Comment: @HåkonHægland: The majority of Perl professionals use `snake_case`, and [`perldoc perstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) discusses it, saying *“It is generally easier to read $var_names_like_this than $VarNamesLikeThis , especially for non-native speakers of English”*. I assure you that the latter looks extremely odd, and is even a little disturbing after seeing nothing but the former in the the vast majority of Perl code. I try to follow the most common standards everywhere, whether I am using Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, JavaScript, Lua etc. All have their own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Good argument. Note that camel case alway starts with a lower case letter `camelCase` whereas Pascal case begins with a capital letter. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase .. So Perl Module names are actually Pascal case.. The nice thing with camelCase is that it is identical to snake_case for single word variables like `$variable`, and you don't have to type the underscore letter, so variable names become shorter.. I agree that snake_case is very readable though..